# Moving a game object through position incrementing

Tags: unity-game-engine

For Unity coding practice, I am trying to move a game object with constant speed towards a target, and I want it to stop moving once it reaches 1.0 or less units of distance; i.e. it only moves while the distance is bigger than 1.0 units.

(I know how to do this through applying force to its rigid body, but this is just for coding practice...)

I cannot figure out why it is not moving though, despite having set the target position in the Inspector, as seen in the attached image.

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 target;
    private float speed;


    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(this.name); // Print the name of the game object this script is attached to.
    }


    void Update()
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target);

        if (distance > 1.0f)
        {
            Vector3 direction = target - transform.position;
            direction.Normalize();
            transform.position += direction * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I don't see the value of *speed* being set anywhere.

Comment: Bless you!  I completely missed that.  Setting it to `1.0f` makes a smooth movement.  Many thanks

Comment: Haha, happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

This is what our good friend LERP is for. LERP is great because you just say "I have two vectors and I want to end up somewhere between them." In this case you want your two vectors to be your mover's position and targets position respectively, and how far you lerp between them will be speed * deltaTime. This saves you all that complicated vector maths.

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you.